# swift - cell label.text is optional

Tags: swift

I have every `label` in my `tableViewCell` displayed correctly, but only my attributeString output is "`optional(1)`"

```
     let mString = String(self.productList?["market_price"].int)
     let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: mString)
     attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, rnge: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
     attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
     self.marketPriceLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```

Comment: The reason is probably the mysterious `.int` function which seems to return an optional and the `String` initializer treats the optional literally. The result of `productList?["market_price"]` is an optional anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
let mInt: Int = (self.productList?["market_price"].int)!
let mString: String = String(mInt)
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: mString)
attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, rnge: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
self.marketPriceLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```